# Wireless networks not working on ASUS laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus, 17.04

I [installed Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/931800/148451) on an older laptop.

Everything seems to be working fine, except the Wifi.

The Wifi networks are not showing in the `ifconfig` output, nor in the UI.

The owner of the laptop said Wifi used to work before, when the laptop was running Windows 10.

Relevant output:

```
$ lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

I tried to restart the `network-manager` service, but that didn't solve it.

I feel like some drivers/modules are missing or have to be loaded, but I don't know how to do that.

How to solve this problem?

---

Note: Wireless was not working in the live USB as well. Wired connection does work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: And after your `rfkill list` output, if no soft or hard blocked, check to see if network manager even sees your wireless card with `iw dev`.

Comment: @Pilot6 No output for `rfkill list`.

Comment: @Yokai No output for any of these two commands.

Comment: Can you give the output of `lshw -C network`? It should show both ethernet and wireless if your wireless card is detected by the kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, duplicate of that question. Installing that driver solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: In the future, this link to a number of linux networking and hardware tools may be of help if you run into problems in the future.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Commands